# how to store the user information in local storage DroidScript

Tags: droidscript

I am using droidscript . and I don't know how to store the user activities in local storage. because my app isn't connected to the internet. my problem is every time the user log in to my app he finds the same things.
so I am looking for a way that could make me store his informations to find it again when he logs in!

Comment: Please try to follow this outline when asking a question to get the best possible answer from the community, welcome! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Per the tutorial on their website, it looks like what your looking to do could be accomplished using a JSON file saved to local storage.

http://androidscript.org/droidscript/tutorials/?tutorials=11_WritingJSONToAFile

Each time the app opens, read the file and load the app according to the settings file.  This would also allow you to save a settings file separate from a data file.

Answer (score 0):

write his informations in file and save it .
`app.WriteFile(file,text);`
to get the informations use :
`app.ReadFile(file);`